# Creation of a map from another map in Java

Tags: java

I have to convert a Map- Map1 into Map2.

Map1:

```
A.B.Key    = "Key"
A.B.Value  = "Value"
A.B.Key1   = "Key1"
A.B.Value1 = "Value1"
A.B.Key2   = "Key2"
A.B.Value2 = "Value2"
```

Map2:

```
Key  = Value
Key1 = Value1
Key2 = Value2
```

Map1 is created from this XML file:

XML File:

```
<A>
  <B>
    <Key> Key </Key>
    <Value> Value </Value>
  </B>
  <B>
    <Key> Key1 </Key>
    <Value> Value1 </Value>
  </B>
  <B>
    <Key> Key2 </Key>
    <Value> Value2 </Value2>
  </B>
</A>
```

I am getting the problem because Map1 contents are not in the order, in which Its mentioned in the XML file. Map1 is something like this:

Actual Map1:

```
A.B.Key2   = "Key2"
A.B.Key    = "Key"
A.B.Value  = "Value"
A.B.Value1 = "Value1"
A.B.Value3 = "Value2"
A.B.Key1   = "Key1"
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Java Collection API there are "Linked..." implementations of the basic interfaces, which are ordered according the element insertion. You could use the [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) for your propose.